# query based on temp table hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to query this in hive. My problem is how to query in hive with TEMP. table.
When I query this, I have got :
Invalid table alias or column reference

```
SELECT CURR_CODE,
    EF_DATE,
    EF_HOUR,
    EF_MINUTE,
    EXPI_DATE,
    MRR,
    CURR_MARKET
FROM
  (SELECT CURR_CODE,
    EF_DATE,
    EF_HOUR,
    EF_MINUTE,
    CASE WHEN TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDA_FICANT IS NULL THEN TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDB_FICANT
    ELSE TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDA_FICANT
    END AS EXPI_DATE,
    M.MRR,
    M.CURR_MARKET
  FROM 
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_1_M_FICANT M,
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_1_4_AB_FICANT A
    WHERE M.CHC = A.CURR_CODE
    ||';'
    ||A.CURR_NO
    AND M.MRR IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY CURR_CODE ASC,
    EF_DATE ASC
  )qwx
UNION ALL
SELECT CURR_CODE,EF_DATE,EF_HOUR,EF_MINUTE,EXPI_DATE,MRR,CURR_MARKET
FROM
  (SELECT M.CURRENCY_CODE AS CURR_CODE,
    EF_DATE,
    EF_HOUR,
    EF_MINUTE,
    TEMP.DM_2_ZEXPIDC_FICANT AS EXPI_DATE,
    M.MRR,
    M.CURR_MARKET
  FROM 
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_2_M_FICANT M ,
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_2_4_AB_FICANT A
  WHERE M.CURRENCY_CODE =A.CURR_CODE
  AND M.MRR IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY CURR_CODE ASC,
  EF_DATE ASC
  )qwz
```

The TEMP tables are shaped from

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDA_FICANT AS SELECT..
```

What went wrong here?
Am I wrong when I try to make temp table?

Comment: You query consists of two subqueries with UNION ALL. Debug them separately. Exception message matters. Which table alias or column is invalid exactly?

Comment: TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDA_FICANT, TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDB_FICANT, and TEMP.DM_2_ZEXPIDC_FICANT

Comment: without them, my query runs good

Comment: Looks like hive wants me refer to M and A tables. TEMP.DM_QUERY_1_M_FICANT , TEMP.DM_QUERY_1_4_AB_FICANT, TEMP.DM_QUERY_2_M_FICANT, TEMP.DM_QUERY_2_4_AB_FICANT

Comment: Do you have access to `TEMP` database in hive?